# IntelliJ code Analyse overview of right side top corner and analyse Inspection shows different data

Tags: intellij-idea, code-inspection, intel-inspector

IntelliJ code Analyse overview of right side top corner and analyse Inspection shows different data
When I hover the  right side top corner of code it shows something like this as inspection analyse [image]

But when I run code Inspection for that same file through Analyse -> Inspec code, it shows different result like below [image]

I need to get that same Analysis data which is shown in right side top corner as the result or log. Is there any other way to get that analyse result as text report or something like that. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify if the information in the "Analysis completed" tooltip had been shown for you before the "Analyze | Inspect Code" action was performed? Was the information in the tooltip updated after the analysis?

Comment: @OlgaKlisho no, It doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Due to performance reasons some of the inspections in IntelliJ IDEA differ at the *Editor level* and while run explicitly with *Analyze | Inspect Code*, i.e. "unused property" or "unused declaration" inspections etc. So thats why the information in "Analysis completed" window and "Inspections results" pane may be different.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Is there any way to get those analyzed data (right side top corner) as a text